# path alias OK for default language, but no alias for others

Tags: i18n-l10n, 9, path-aliases

My site is in D9, mainly in French, with some pages in English.

I have an old page (note 553 written in D6 in 2017), which can be correctly accessed in French with https://mysite/myoldpage and in English with https://mysite/en/myoldpage.

I've just written a new page in French (https://mysite/mynewpage) and translated it in English. But the translated page is only accessible with https://mysite/en/node/997.

I don't understand why the old page works perfectly and not the new one.

I see a difference in https://mysite/node/553/translations and in https://mysite/node/997/translations. For the old one, I see a "source language" column. For the new one, There is no such column (but I do see the 2 lines for the 2 languages).

Parts of my conf:

- Language selection is firstly by URL.
- I use pathauto, but not for "pages"

Any hint appreciated!

Comment: The old node probably has an alias with the language code UND (-not specified-). You can add one in the alias table, but not in the node edit form. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2689459. The column source language only shows when there are translations with a source language other than the original language, but this is not connected to this alias issue.

Comment: 4uk4, you are right! The alias of the new page was defined as in French. I went in /admin/config/search/path, edited my new alias, and set its language as "not specified". English translation is now correctly at /en/mynewpage. Thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old node probably has an alias with the language code UND (-not specified-). You can add one in the alias table

```
www.example.com/admin/config/search/path
```

but not in the node edit form. See https://drupal.org/node/2689459.

The column source language only shows when there are translations with a source language other than the original language, but this is not connected to this alias issue.